# TSQL filter that I do not understand, 2 versions that I thought would return the same data do not

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I have a SQL statement that was not returning data like it should (MSSQL Server), in part of the query I had this

```
and t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2
```

turns out if I changed that to

```
and (t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2 OR t.Invc_Sts_Cd IS NULL)
```

then it returned the data I expected, I would have thought those 2 things would be equivalent but obviously not in TSQL.

Here is the full Statement

```
SELECT t.tm_sht_id,0
FROM tm_sht t 
    INNER JOIN cand c ON c.cand_id = t.cand_id
    LEFT JOIN SOW_Resource sr on c.Req_Id = sr.Req_Id and (sr.Invoice_Timesheets=1 OR sr.Invoice_Timesheets is NULL)
WHERE  t.tm_sht_sts_cd = 3 
AND     t.apvd_dt >= @Last_Run_Time 
and c.clnt_org_id = @Org_Id 
and (t.Suspend_Fg <> 1)
and (t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2 OR t.Invc_Sts_Cd IS NULL)
```

My question is why do those return different data sets?

Comment: `NULL` is UNKNOWN, therefor, you cannot tell whether it is equal to `2` or not. The comparison returns `NULL`, which is not `TRUE`.

Comment: NULL is not a value and hence cannot be compared to anything.. have a look at https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/#:~:text=Therefore%20NULL%20is%20neither%20equal,something%20that%20doesn't%20exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2` and `(t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2 OR t.Invc_Sts_Cd IS NULL)` are **not** equivalent, but they are similar.

The key thing you need to understand here is how `NULL` values work. Nothing is equal to or not equal to `NULL`, including `NULL` itself; `NULL = NULL` isn't `TRUE` (though is isn't `FALSE` either, but I come to that shortly). The only way to evaluate against a `NULL` is using `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

When doing a comparison against `NULL`, if you don't use `IS (NOT) NULL` then the result will be `UNKNOWN`. For a expression like `WHERE Column = 1` then it isn't a problem when `Column` has the value `NULL`, as it isn't `1`. For other expressions, it does.

For `WHERE Column <> 2`, when `Column` has the value `NULL` it gives result the `UNKNOWN`, which importantly is **not** `TRUE`. Thus the row does not meet to criteria.

The same is true for an expression like `WHERE NOT(Column = 1)`. If `Column` has the value `NULL`, then `Column = 1` = `UNKNOWN` and `NOT(UNKNOWN)` is still `UNKNOWN`.

Therefore, if you have `NULL` values, and are performiong comparisons which rely on them, you *must* include `IS NULL` and/or `IS NOT NULL` logic.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, `NULL` means you *don't know* what the value is. This is subtly different than not having a value at all. When you don't know what the value is, it's still possible the value *might be* `2`, and therefore `NULL <> 2` could still possibly be false... but, again, the result is you *don't know*.

Therefore, if `t.Invc_Sts_Cd` is `NULL`, then `t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2` **must** evaluate as... `NULL`, because we *don't know* what the result is. And `NULL` is falsy when you force it into a true/false boolean situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about T-SQL, but SQL in general. NULL is the unknown value. If you compare it with some value, the result is hence unknown (i.e. it could or could not match the value).

So both

```
and t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2
```

and

```
and t.Invc_Sts_Cd = 2
```

exclude NULLs from the result, because for a NULL in Invc_Sts_Cd neither expression results in TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

The crux here is that the logical comparison:

```
t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2
```

is actually *false* when the `Invc_Sts_Cd` value is `NULL`.  The reason for this is that comparing `NULL` to any other value yields the value `NULL`, which will evaluate to false when it appears inside a `WHERE` clause.

The second version of your logic is correct:

```
and (t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2 OR t.Invc_Sts_Cd IS NULL)
```

This will be true when either `Invc_Sts_Cd` is *not* equal to 2, *or* this value happens to be `NULL`.

Comment: *"is actually false when the `Invc_Sts_Cd` value is `NULL`"* I disagree with this. `t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2` doesn't resolve to `FALSE` when `t.Invc_Sts_Cd` has a value of `NULL`, it evaluates to `UNKNOWN`. This is a very important distinction. For example, otherwise `NOT(t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2)` would evaluate to `TRUE` if `t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2` evaluated for `FALSE`

Comment: Funny.  You comment under my answer while not saying anything to Joel's response which basically says the same exact thing.

Comment: I've only just read your answer and written the comment! Give me a chance to read the others, Tim. :)

Comment: Joel's answers, reading it, isn't quite the same however, Tim; or at least in my opinion. Joel states that `NULL <> 2` evaluates to `NULL`, which is true, and then goes onto to say that a result that is `NULL` is a "falsy". I read this to mean "not `TRUE`" rather than them explicitly saying `NULL` means `FALSE`, as they explicitly use "false" later. The key thing I'm picking up here, is that your answer (suggests) that `t.Invc_Sts_Cd <> 2` evaluates to `FALSE` when `t.Invc_Sts_Cd` has the value `NULL`; which we explicitly know is not true (irony intended).